# Write CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

I want write csv (`outfile`) file from another csv file (`infile`). In `infile` csv data write like this `OF0A0C,00,D0,0F11AFCB` I want to write to `outfile` same as`infile` but I get like this `"\r \n 0,F,0,A,0,C,","0,0,","D,0,","0,F,1,1,A,F,C,B \r \n`
My code like this :

```
with open ("from_baryon.csv", "r") as inFile:
    with open (self.filename, "a") as outFile:
        for line in inFile:
            OutFile = csv.writer (outFile)
            OutFile.writerow (line)
```

After write I want to save every data in row to list like this `Data = [[length_of_all_data],[length_data_row_1,datarow1],[length_data_row_2,datarow1datarow2],[length_data_row_3,datarow1datarow3]]`

I confused to  save the with list mode like that. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues -

1. You should read the input csv file using `csv` module's `csv.reader()` , instead of iterating over its lines, since when you iterate over its lines, you get the line back as a string in the iteration - `for line in inFile:` , and then you are writing this line back using `OutFile.writerow(line)` , hence it writes each character into different columns.
2. You do not need to create separate `OutFile = csv.writer (outFile)` for every line.

Example code -

```
with open ("from_baryon.csv", "r") as inFile:
    with open (self.filename, "a") as outFile:
        out_file = csv.writer (outFile)
        in_reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        for row in in_reader:
            out_file.writerow(row)
```

---

EDIT: For the second issue that is updated, you can create a list and a counter to keep track of the complete length. Example -

```
with open ("from_baryon.csv", "r") as inFile:
    with open (self.filename, "a") as outFile:
        out_file = csv.writer (outFile)
        in_reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        data = []
        lencount = 0
        for row in in_reader:
            out_file.writerow(row)
            tlen = len(''.join(row))
            data.append([tlen] + row)
            lencount += tlen
        data.insert(0,[lencount])
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my first problem. Do you have any idea for second problem?

Comment: What is the second problem? I didn't clearly understand. Are you looking for `OutFile.writerows(data)` ?

Comment: No, I just edit my post. My second problem is save to list

Comment: For second issue, you can explain with examples?

Comment: Example: In my `outfile` csv the data like this : `"0F0A0C,00,0FF11C", "0F0A0C,00,0FF11D"` I want save to list like this : `[[32],[16,0F0A0C,00,0FF11C],[16,0F0A0C,00,0FF11C]]` thank you.

Comment: I get error like this `can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` error on `data.append ([tlen]+line)`

Comment: are you still using the complete code i gave? I my code, `row` is a list, but seems like you are still using your code where `line` is a string.