# Write datas to csv file

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I have csv problem.
I have a code to extract data from Futbin website but I don't find how to do to export these datas to a csv file.
The datas shown in Python are exactly what I need so the last step for me is to exctract them.

Here is the code :

```
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime

player_ids = {  
  'Maguire OTW': 50534911,  
  'Pulisic OTW' : 50559444,

}

for (name,id) in player_ids.items():
    r = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/20/playerGraph?type=yesterday&year=20&player={0}'.format(id))
    data = r.json()

    print()
    print(name)   
    #Change ps to xbox or pc to get other prices
    for price in data['ps']:
        #There is extra zeroes in response.
        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(price[0] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        price = price[1]
        print(date,price)
```

Thanks a lot for your help

> **Copy Comment**: When I add this at the end of the code :
>
> ```
> with open('yesterdayok.csv', 'w') as csv_file: 
>     csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file) 
>     csv_writer.writerow(date)
> ```
>
> it creates the csv file but **inside there's only 1 date**, I need all the datas generated by the code.

Comment: What data do you want to write to the csv file? In what format?

Comment: Consider using pandas to convert the JSON response to a csv.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558077/convert-json-to-csv-with-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write CSV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077478/write-csv-python)

Comment: I'd like to write the datas I can see in python when I run this code to a csv file, nothing more. And I don't know how to code this.

Comment: ***"inside there's only 1 date"***: [Edit] your question and show the output of `print(date)` before the line `.writerow(date)`. Read about [common-sequence-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: In fact I want the date and the price to go to the csv file

Comment: print(date,price) shows me exactly what I expect in python (several dates and prices) but I have no idea what to write in code to export these datas in a csv file